# Equality of Integrands

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Let $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$. That is, two integrals have the same value. Is the integrands are same? If not equals, so under what conditions integrands are same?

Answer (score 2):

No they are not necessarily equal, consider $a=0,b=1$ and $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=2x$.

As far as I know, there is no simple or no too restrictive general conditions for the integrands to be the same unless you allow the boundaries to move.

For example : let $I$ an interval, and $f$ and $g$ continuous functions on $I$, if $\forall a,b, \in I$ $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$ then $f \equiv g$ on $I$.